# Invert axis on highchart diagram with data from table

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, diagram

I have a table which shows the EventID Count for Windows Logs for every month.

And now I would like to have this in a Line-Diagram where you have the EventIDs as the label, the count on the yAxis and the month on the xAxis.

Here is what I did:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6XHu/)

How do I invert the Axis?

When I try it like this it's not working:

```
chart: {
        inverted: true
    },
```

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Would be much better if you had the data in an array as opposed to HTML table, is that possible at all?

Comment: I get my table data from an sql query which I do with php. The result of the query is in a table format. Than i overgive my table result from the php to the html.

I think I could convert the result from the query from the table format to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `switchRowsAndColumns` option from the data module to achieve this.

Example ([JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6XHu/1/)):

```
data: {
    table: document.getElementById('datatable'),
    switchRowsAndColumns: true
}
```

The data module isn't that well documented, but the options can be found [in the source code](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js), in the comments/documentation at the top.

Comment: +1 Nice answer and well done for digging through the source ;)